# Unwanted Duplicate Dynamic Lists Generated for Two Different Lightning Combo Boxes

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Help:
  I have successfully created two different combo boxes in a lightning component. The first one displays a dynamic lists of account records under the Account combo box while the second combo box displays a dynamic list of user records under it. However, when I do the autocomplete search and get the list results for one combo box, I'm noticing that this same list is also underneath the other combo box and vice versa(?!).
Here is the Lightning Component code:

```
 <div class="slds-form-element__row">
                    <div class="slds-form-element slds-size_1-of-2 slds-m-horizontal_small">
                        <div class="slds-form-element-label">
                            <output value="Account" class="slds-form-element-label"></output>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-combobox_container slds-has-inline-listbox ">
                            <div class="slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click slds-is-open" 
                                 aria-expanded="true" aria-haspopup="listbox" role="combobox">
                                <div class="slds-combobox__form-element slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_right">
                                    <div> 
                                        <aura:if isTrue="{! empty(v.accountId) }"> 
                                            <input type="text" class="slds-input slds-combobox__input" id="combobox-unique-id" 
                                                   aria-activedescendant="listbox-option-unique-id-01" aria-autocomplete="list" 
                                                   aria-controls="listbox-unique-id" autocomplete="on" role="combobox" 
                                                   placeholder="{!v.placeholder}" value="{!v.accName}"
                                                   onkeyup="{!c.serverCall}" label="Account"/>
                                        </aura:if>
                                        <aura:if isTrue="{! !empty(v.accountId) }">
                                            <span class="slds-pill slds-pill_link fullWidth slds-m-around_xx-small"> 
                                                <a href="javascript:void(0);" 
                                                   class="slds-pill__action slds-p-left_small slds-p-right_small" title="{!v.accName}">
                                                    <lightning:icon iconName="{!v.lookupIcon}" size="small"/>
                                                    <span class="slds-pill__label slds-p-left_small slds-p-right_small">{!v.accName}</span>
                                                </a>
                                                <button onclick="{!c.clearSelection}" 
                                                        class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon slds-pill__remove" 
                                                        title="Remove">
                                                    <lightning:icon iconName="utility:close" size="small" 
                                                                    alternativeText="Press delete or backspace to remove"/>
                                                    <span class="slds-assistive-text" >Remove</span>
                                                </button>
                                            </span> 

                                        </aura:if> 
                                    </div> 
                                </div>
                                <aura:if isTrue="{! greaterthanorequal(v.server_result.length,1) }"> 
                                    <div id="listbox-unique-id" role="listbox">
                                        <ul class="slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical slds-dropdown slds-dropdown_fluid" role="presentation"
                                            style="display: block; min-width: auto; max-width: 100% ; width: 100%;">
                                            <aura:iteration items="{!v.server_result}" var="item" indexVar="i">
                                                <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item" data-selectedIndex="{#i}" id="{#i}"  
                                                    onclick="{!c.itemSelected}">
                                                    <span id="{#'Account_'+i}"  
                                                          class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_entity 
                                                                 slds-listbox__option_has-meta" 
                                                          role="option">
                                                        <span class="slds-media__figure optionIcon">
                                                            <span class="slds-icon_container" >
                                                                <lightning:icon iconName="{#v.lookupIcon}" size="small"/>
                                                                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Account</span>
                                                            </span>
                                                        </span>
                                                        <span class="slds-media__body singleRow">
                                                            <span 
                                                                  class="optionTitle slds-listbox__option-text 
                                                                         slds-listbox__option-text_entity" >{#item.SObjectLabel}</span>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </span>
                                                </li>
                                            </aura:iteration> 
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </aura:if> 
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
```

```
                                            <input type="text" class="slds-input slds-combobox__input" id="combobox-unique-2id" 
                                                   aria-activedescendant="listbox-option-unique-id-02" aria-autocomplete="list" 
                                                   aria-controls="listbox-unique-2id" autocomplete="on" role="combobox" 
                                                   placeholder="{!v.placeholderBDM}" value="{!v.bdmName}"
                                                   onkeyup="{!c.serverCallBDM}" label="BDM Sender"/>
                                        </aura:if>
                                        <aura:if isTrue="{! !empty(v.bdmId) }">
                                            <span class="slds-pill slds-pill_link fullWidth slds-m-around_xx-small"> 
                                                <a href="javascript:void(0);" 
                                                   class="slds-pill__action slds-p-left_small slds-p-right_small" title="{!v.bdmName}">
                                                    <lightning:icon iconName="{!v.lookupIconBDM}" size="small"/>
                                                    <span class="slds-pill__label slds-p-left_small slds-p-right_small">{!v.bdmName}</span>
                                                </a>
                                                <button onclick="{!c.clearSelectionBDM}" 
                                                        class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon slds-pill__remove" 
                                                        title="Remove">
                                                    <lightning:icon iconName="utility:close" size="small" 
                                                                    alternativeText="Press delete or backspace to remove"/>
                                                    <span class="slds-assistive-text" >Remove</span>
                                                </button>
                                            </span> 

                                        </aura:if> 
                                    </div> 
                                </div>
                                <aura:if isTrue="{! greaterthanorequal(v.server_result.length,1) }"> 
                                    <div id="listbox-unique-id" role="listbox">
                                        <ul class="slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical slds-dropdown slds-dropdown_fluid" role="presentation"
                                            style="display: block; min-width: auto; max-width: 100% ; width: 100%;">
                                            <aura:iteration items="{!v.server_result}" var="item" indexVar="i">
                                                <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item" data-selectedIndex="{#i}" id="{#i}"  
                                                    onclick="{!c.itemSelectedBDM}">
                                                    <span id="{#'User_'+i}"  
                                                          class="slds-media-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_entity 
                                                                 slds-listbox__option_has-meta" 
                                                          role="option">
                                                        <span class="slds-media__figure optionIcon">
                                                            <span class="slds-icon_container" >
                                                                <lightning:icon iconName="{#v.lookupIconBDM}" size="small"/>
                                                                <span class="slds-assistive-text">User</span>
                                                            </span>
                                                        </span>
                                                        <span class="slds-media__body singleRow">
                                                            <span 
                                                                  class="optionTitle slds-listbox__option-text 
                                                                         slds-listbox__option-text_entity" >{#item.SObjectLabel}</span>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </span>
                                                </li>
                                            </aura:iteration> 
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </aura:if> 
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-form-element slds-size_1-of-2 slds-m-horizontal_small" ></div>
                </div>
```

Comment: with out adding component code,it's very hard to give solution , so can u update question with code

Comment: hi @sdandamud1   I couldn't post the entire Lightning component code, due to size constrains, just the code for both combo boxes. I Hope this is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I discovered what might be the problem.

1. I need to set the following near the `if isTrue="{! greaterthanorequal(v.server_result.length,1`) tag:

```
id="listbox-unique-id
```

to

```
id="listbox-unique-#
```

Where # is set  to some alphanumeric number like '02' or '01'.

2. I also need to copy certain component attribute variables  from the Account object to the BDM ( User object ) where I then affix the 'BDM' string to the end of those variables.
3. I need to do the same for the functions in the Handler. ( *I know there could be a more convenient way to do this without duplication so much code but I want to make sure it works before I attempt that.*)
   To prove this I did a portion of the two steps mentioned above and was able to see that the dynamic list was only positioned  under the combo box where I performed the auto-completion search..